# Group with relations, must identity elements be combination of the relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle g_1,\dots, g_m\mid r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k\rangle$, where $r_i$ are relations, e.g. $r_1=g_{2}^{-1}g_3g_4=1$.

Suppose $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}=1$, that is, a product of generators that is equal to the identity.

Further suppose $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}$ is a reduced word, that is, there are no such terms like $gg^{-1}$ in the expression.

Can we conclude that $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}$ is a product of the relations $r_i$? Is this obvious or does it need a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: No of course not. Is that was true then we would have a very easy solution to the word problem in finitely presented groups! In general, the word is a product of conjugates of the $r_i$ in the free group. (In any case, as it stands your question does not make much sense. What do you mean by a product of relations?)

Comment: Well, as posed, it is true, since $r_j=1$ in $G$, their product is still $1$, hence equals to $g_{i_1}\dots g_{i_n}$ once it's supposed to be $1$. But this is true only in $G$ and not on the level of reduced words.

Comment: @Berci I am not sure about that. I think if you insist on being pedantic, then the generators $g_i$ are elements of the free group rather than of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you may not conclude that $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}$ is a product of relations $r_i$.

Instead, the following holds. I will write $U=_G V$ to mean that the words $U$ and $V$ define the same element of the group $G$, while $U\equiv V$ means they define the same element of the ambient free group.

> If $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}=_G1$ then there exist $h_1, \ldots, h_m\in F(g_j)$ such that $g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_n}\equiv h_{j_1}r_{j_1}h_{j_1}^{-1}\cdots h_{j_p}r_{j_p}h_{j_p}^{-1}$.

That is, your word is the product of *conjugates of* relators, not simply the product of relators. This is because the presentation $G=\langle g_1, \ldots, g_m\mid r_1, \ldots, r_k\rangle$ is notation for the quotient group $F(g_1, \ldots, g_m)/N$ where $N$ is the normal closure of the elements $r_1, \ldots, r_k\in F(g_1, \ldots, g_m)$ (often written $N=\langle\langle r_1, \ldots, r_k\rangle\rangle$).

For more details, see Section 2.1 of the book *Combinatorial group theory* by Magnus, Karrass and Solitar. You should also read over Chapter 1 - it is gory, but everyone should read it once so you understand the pedantry surrounding group presentations.

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: By the way is this a deep result? (the fact that the word must be a product of conjugates of relators) Or is it something that can be explained in a few lines?

Comment: Once free groups have been formally set up using equivalence classes of words/free reduction etc. it follows quickly from what I have written. (Basically, the "normal closure" of a set $S$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $S$. Hence, if $s\in S$ then each conjugate of $s$ is in $N$, and you can take the set of all such conjugates as an (infinite) generating set for $N$. Your result follows.)